# How can I use @ in PetaPoco queries

Tags: sql, petapoco

I am trying to use @@ROWCOUNT for an execute query in PetaPoco.

Problem is, it consider @@ROWCOUNT like "@ROWCOUNT" parameter because of the @.

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@ROWCOUNT".
```

Here is the execute query code

```
this.Execute(@"
            UPDATE  myTable
            SET     foo = @2
            WHERE   bar = @0
                AND bor = @1

            IF  @@ROWCOUNT=0
                INSERT INTO myTable
                (bar, bor, foo)
                VALUES
                (@0, @1, @2)", myItem.bar
                                , myItem.bor
                                , myItem.foo);
```

I've searched to find if there was any specific syntax to use for PetaPoco SQL query, but I can't find any information about using @ for something else then parameters.
If there is no way to do it, is there any ways I can do an insert if the update item doesn't exist? (I'd rather avoid having to use a SELECT to see if the entry exist)

Comment: I take it you're using sql server - what version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can double escape the @@ like this. @@@ROWCOUNT.

You can see this technique used in the PetaPoco.cs file in the ExecuteInsert method.

```
public override object ExecuteInsert(
    Database db, 
    System.Data.IDbCommand cmd, 
    string PrimaryKeyName)
{
    db.ExecuteNonQueryHelper(cmd);
    return db.ExecuteScalar<object>("SELECT @@@IDENTITY AS NewID;");
}
```